# WinAPI crashes VBA on Function ClipBoard_GetData() for a large data set

Tags: vba, winapi, excel, clipboard, vnc

So I wrote a 180 page program in VBA that is fairly robust and works great, except the clipboard doesn't work when running simultaneously with any VNC viewer (RealVNC, logmein, etc.)  After digging around I found this was a somewhat known but rare issue, so Windows wrote API code to utilize getting data from and sending data to the clipboard:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn124100.aspx

Function ClipBoard_SetData(MyString As String) works fine with any data set I've tried. And Function ClipBoard_GetData() works fine with a small data set, but when I try it with a 80KB data set it crashes excel every time.

Any help with running VBA next to a VNC viewer or Win API code would be greatly appreciated.  Here is WinAPI code:

```
Declare Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) _
   As Long
Declare Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) _
   As Long
Declare Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal wFlags As Long, _
   ByVal dwBytes As Long) As Long
Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "User32" () As Long
Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "User32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) _
   As Long
Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "User32" () As Long
Declare Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, _
   ByVal lpString2 As Any) As Long
Declare Function SetClipboardData Lib "User32" (ByVal wFormat _
   As Long, ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Declare Function GetClipboardData Lib "User32" (ByVal wFormat As _
   Long) As Long
Declare Function GlobalSize Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) _
   As Long

Public Const GHND = &H42
Public Const CF_TEXT = 1
Public Const MAXSIZE = 4096

Function ClipBoard_SetData(MyString As String)
   Dim hGlobalMemory As Long, lpGlobalMemory As Long
   Dim hClipMemory As Long, X As Long

   ' Allocate moveable global memory.
   '-------------------------------------------
   hGlobalMemory = GlobalAlloc(GHND, Len(MyString) + 1)

   ' Lock the block to get a far pointer
   ' to this memory.
   lpGlobalMemory = GlobalLock(hGlobalMemory)

   ' Copy the string to this global memory.
   lpGlobalMemory = lstrcpy(lpGlobalMemory, MyString)

   ' Unlock the memory.
   If GlobalUnlock(hGlobalMemory) <> 0 Then
      MsgBox "Could not unlock memory location. Copy aborted."
      GoTo OutOfHere2
   End If

   ' Open the Clipboard to copy data to.
   If OpenClipboard(0&) = 0 Then
      MsgBox "Could not open the Clipboard. Copy aborted."
      Exit Function
   End If

   ' Clear the Clipboard.
   X = EmptyClipboard()

   ' Copy the data to the Clipboard.
   hClipMemory = SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hGlobalMemory)

OutOfHere2:

   If CloseClipboard() = 0 Then
      MsgBox "Could not close Clipboard."
   End If

   End Function

Function ClipBoard_GetData()
   Dim hClipMemory As Long
   Dim lpClipMemory As Long
   Dim MyString As String
   Dim RetVal As Long

   If OpenClipboard(0&) = 0 Then
      MsgBox "Cannot open Clipboard. Another app. may have it open"
      Exit Function
   End If

   ' Obtain the handle to the global memory
   ' block that is referencing the text.
   hClipMemory = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT)
   If IsNull(hClipMemory) Then
      MsgBox "Could not allocate memory"
      GoTo OutOfHere
   End If

   ' Lock Clipboard memory so we can reference
   ' the actual data string.
   lpClipMemory = GlobalLock(hClipMemory)

   If Not IsNull(lpClipMemory) Then
      MyString = Space$(MAXSIZE)
      RetVal = lstrcpy(MyString, lpClipMemory)
      RetVal = GlobalUnlock(hClipMemory)

      ' Peel off the null terminating character.
      MyString = Mid(MyString, 1, InStr(1, MyString, Chr$(0), 0) - 1)
   Else
      MsgBox "Could not lock memory to copy string from."
   End If

OutOfHere:

   RetVal = CloseClipboard()
   ClipBoard_GetData = MyString

End Function
```

Comment: Your code has a whole lot of problems. I don't know if any one of them is responsible for your crash but you need to fix these before you can attempt to find the crash. `IsNull()` cannot be used to check a null pointer/handle from an API call. You must check against `0` instead. You must also check the return value of every single API call for error conditions - you rarely do.

Comment: Also, your constant definitions are all `Variant`-s because you left out the `As Long` part. You should also _never, ever_ use `Goto` - it's a bad programming practice to use it. Change your code such that conditional statements route program flow to the right place without `Goto`. (The VBA `On Error Goto...` construct is an exception - it's really a badly named try-catch block.)

Comment: Can you try stepping through the code? Which line does it crash on?  @xxbbcc the OP got the code straight from the msdn link, so no great surprise that it's a bit borked ;)

Comment: @Blackhawk Lol, I didn't realize that. I didn't check the link.

Comment: @Blackhawk Awesome. The max=4046 and lstrcpy is indeed in the msdn link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You allocate a string of MAXSIZE (4096) spaces and use `lstrcpy` to override it with the clipboard content. No surprise if Excel crash when there is 80k in the Clipboard. Use `lstrlen` to know the size of the actual content of the clipboard.